# Get next highest number relative to variable

Tags: salesforce, formula

I am writing a formula field and pretty close, but cannot figure out how to do the following.

I have a Billing Date field, and then I have the option for clients to choose the frequency of their billing. They can choose: Annual, Semi-Annual, Quarterly, and Monthly.

I wrote a formula to find what the Next Billing Date is for all of these options, except quarterly. I cannot figure it out.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 /* What months are quarterly payments due? */ 
    
    MOD(MONTH(Billing_Date__c)+3,12)
    MOD(MONTH(Billing_Date__c)+5,12)
    MOD(MONTH(Billing_Date__c)+9,12)
    MOD(MONTH(Billing_Date__c)+11,12)

/* What month is it right now */
    
    MONTH(TODAY())

/* Of those four numbers, what is the next highest number relative to today? */
```

I am calculating a number - month of the current day (MONTH(TODAY()).

**TL;DR**

> I have a number (7) and I have four other numbers (9, 11, 3, 6
> ). I want the next highest number, assuming I cannot go backwards. In
> this example, the answer would be 9.

Answer (score 0):

Your accounting quarter ends are weird, really "3, 6, 9, 11", not "... 12"? What do you do in December?

If that's a typo and it should be 12 - you can try to do some clever formula, `CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3) * 3` might be a good start. See also https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5, look for "quarter".

If it's really 11 - sometimes simplest solutions are best. Don't be clever, think of the poor maintenance guy that will look at it in 2 months' time.

```
CASE(MONTH(TODAY()),
1,3,
2,3,
3,3,
4,6,
5,6,
6,6,
7,9,
8,9,
9,9,
11 /* default, because why not. although in this case it hides that "what are you going to do in December" ugliness */
)
```

Boring, easy to read, fast to execute.